# Custom taxonomy only shows 0 in autocomplete for terms and "Choose from the most used tags"

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, autocomplete

I have a custom post type (`rezept` that I added a custom taxonomy `Allergiefrei` to. I got this working so far. Adding terms to the custom taxonomy's box works, too, but autocomplete and 'Choose from the most used tags' only shows "0".

Here's the code where I register the custom taxonomy:

```
function register_rezept_taxonomies() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'Allergiefrei',
    'rezept',
    array(
      'label' => 'Allergien',
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'allergien')
    )
  );
}

add_action('init', 'register_rezept_taxonomies');
```

I'm defining custom taxonomies and the post type in a plugin.

Comment: You state that you have created the terms, but have you _used_ any of them?

Comment: Yes, if by *used* you mean "attached them to the post and saved it" (I checked in the database, too).

To be clear, autocomplete and 'Choose from the most used tags' show a literal ``0``, not an empty input field.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can't use uppercase taxonomy ids. Those work, mostly, but when WordPress sanitizes Ajax calls, everything uppercase is converted to lower case and it won't find the correct taxonomy.

The solution is to only define and use lowercase taxonomy ids.

Comment: _The solution is to only define and use lowercase taxonomy ids._  Do you mean the `Slug` and `Name` can only be lowercase?